# How to make Athena process multiple queries concurrently

Tags: concurrency, amazon-athena

I'm launching several concurrent queries to Athena via a Python application.

Given Athena's history of queries, it seems that multiple queries are all indeed received at the same time by Athena, and processed concurrently.

However, it turns out that the overall query running time is not that different from sending queries one after the other.

Example: sending three queries sequentially vs concurrently:

```sh
# sequentially
           received at       took      finished at
query_1       22:01:14         6s         22:01:20
query_2       22:01:20         6s         22:01:27
query_3       22:01:27         5s         22:01:25

# concurrently
           received at       took      finished at
query_1       22:02:25        17s         22:02:42
query_2       22:02:25        17s         22:02:42
query_3       22:02:25        17s         22:02:42
```

According to these results, in the second case, it seems that Athena, although pretending to be treating the queries concurrently, effectively processed them in a sequential manner.

Is there some configuration I wouldn't be aware of, to make Athena effectively process multiple queries concurrently? Ideally, in this example, the three queries processed concurrently would take a global running time of 6s (the longest time of the three individual queries).

Note: these are three queries targeting the same database/table, backed by the same (single) Parquet file in S3. This Parquet file is approx. 70Mb big and has 2.5M rows with a half-dozen columns.

Comment: Athena will run queries concurrently and it's very unlikely that the numbers you are seeing are due to Athena. To figure out what it is you have to give us some more context, the code you use to produce the measurements, for example. How are you waiting for the queries to complete?

Comment: @Theo thanks for your comment — these numbers are coming straight from Athena's history log of queries, not from my system.

Comment: Show us the code that started the queries and the code that extracted the numbers from the query history. It looks very unlikely that three queries would have the exact start and end durations when we're talking 17 seconds runtime. We run hundreds of concurrent queries and don't see this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

In general the way you run concurrent queries in Athena is to run as many `StartQueryExecution` calls as you need, collect the query execution IDs, and then poll using `GetQueryExecution` for each one to be completed. Athena runs each query independently, concurrently, and asynchronously.

Depending on how long you wait between polling each query execution ID it may look like queries take different amounts of time. You can use the `Statistics.EngineExecutionTimeInMillis` property of the response from `GetQueryExecution` to see how long the query executed in Athena, and the difference between the `Status.SubmissionDateTime` and `Status.CompletionDateTime` properties to see the total time between when Athena received the query and when the response was available. Usually these two numbers are very close, and if there is a difference your query got queued internally in Athena.

The numbers in your question look unlikely. That they ended on the exact same second after running for 17 seconds looks suspicious. How many times did you run your experiment? If you look at `Statistics.EngineExecutionTimeInMillis` do they differ in the number of milliseconds, or are all numbers identical? Did you set `ClientRequestToken`, and if so, was it the same value for all three queries (in that case you actually only ran one).

What do you mean by "concurrently", do you start and poll from different threads, or poll in a single loop? How long did you wait between each poll call?